# How to Run multiple dependent applications from Tomcat locally by deploying their war?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, deployment, war

I have 4 war files of 4 Grails and Java applications which I want to deploy on Apache Tomcat 9 locally. If one of these applications need to run first and then others, how should I deploy them? Currently I have created 4 folders in tomcat directory and pasted the respective wars. When I start tomcat it picks up all one by one to deploy but I don't know if it should pick them up in sequence for proper deployment because I am getting errors in log. How should I deploy them?

```
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
```

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
>        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
>   invoke method getAt() on null object

Another in log

```
[localhost-startStop-1]
```

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file
>       03-Jan-2017 01:11:04.950 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/(app
>   name)] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: I think the error(BeanCreationException) is self explanatory. And for the sequencing stuff: There is no expected startup order. Neither the Servlet spec nor Tomcat define one. You can't rely on the apps starting in any particular order. This is what Tomcat Wiki says.

Answer (score 0):

A DevOps approach using Jenkins might solve your issue.

You can build and/or deploy your applications in a prescribed order with FreeStyle jobs. We do this routinely off code commits in our CI/CD environment in AWS.

No reason this could not be done in a non-AWS environment also.